# Rich text box styles and markup

Tags: infopath, markup

I have a Rich TextBox control with Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks). When I create multiple views for that, list styles and markup are not displayed in SharePoint ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a rich text box control with Enhanced rich text (Rich text with
>   pictures, tables, and hyperlinks). when i create multiple views for
>   that list styles and markup not displayed in sharepoint ribbion.

Since you tagged your question by "infopath", I presume that you ask about Infopath Web Part page.
In this case you are not supposed to see Infopath ribbon on sharepoint ribbon as well as you cannot have the same control between views. Probably you are confusing a control, as visual representation of an underlying data field, with a datafield on the basis of which you created the control. The latter can be used for creating multiple controls but control can be bound to one data field at one time only.

In this case, of using Infopath form, you should see styles and markup on ribbon provided by Infopath Filler, if you run the form on client,  or through Sharepoint Server (Infopath Form Services), if run in browser. And the latter is enterprise feature, not available through free Sharepoint Foundation or some Sharepoint Online plans.

[image: The Infopath XML data form saved in a sharepoint form library]

**Fig.1. The Infopath XML data form in a sharepoint form library**

[image: Fig.2. The Infopath form edited in Browser (having chosen **Edit in browser** context choice)]
**Fig.2. The Infopath form edited in Browser (having chosen "Edit in browser" context choice, cf. Fig.1)**

[image: Fig.3. The Infopath form edited in Filler (having chosen "Edit in Microsoft Infopath" context choice)]
**Fig.3. The Infopath form edited in Filler (having chosen "Edit in Microsoft Infopath" context choice, cf. Fig.1)**

Upon creating multiple view in Infopath form template, I do not see how this behaviour is different.